# System.ServiceModel.FaultException in System.dll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, faultexception

I am trying to consume a remote ASP.NET WebMethod using the Windows Phone SDK 7.1
I have the following C# Code:

```
public static PublicServices.RegisteredServicesSoapClient taarafClient;

App.taarafClient.FetchStreamCompleted +=
  new EventHandler<PublicServices.FetchStreamCompletedEventArgs>(
  taarafClient_FetchStreamCompleted);
```

When running this code I am getting the exception in the title.

I am using a Service Reference: The exception is here:

```
public Taaraf.PublicServices.FetchStreamResponse EndFetchStream(
  System.IAsyncResult result)
{
    object[] _args = new object[0];
    Taaraf.PublicServices.FetchStreamResponse _result =
      (Taaraf.PublicServices.FetchStreamResponse)
      base.EndInvoke("FetchStream", _args, result);
    return _result;
}
```

Comment: What's the `InnerException` on the `FaultException`?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is the `FetchStream` method expecting for the args parameter? (I was not aware you could actually serialize a zero length array, does passing *null* instead of *_args* work?).

Answer (score 4):

Based on the `InnerException` details you've provided the server is throwing an `NullReferenceException`. Is this a service you control? To confirm that it's the service - and not WP7's service client - try creating a simple console application, passing in the same values, and seeing if it generates the same error.

But to me it definitely looks like the error is on the **server** side. By creating a simple console application you'll hopefully eliminate it being a WP7 specific issue and a more general issue to be fixed in the service.

Comment: Yes I do control the service. However, calling it with jQuery and WindowsRT seems to work fine. It's just Windows Phone 7 that's having this issue...

Comment: Can you post the service interface you're calling? Also, what's the actual service call you're making? You've not actually included where you're calling the service or what the parameters are.

Comment: Can you post the arguments you're using ? I've just added a reference to it and called `FetchStreamAsync("Client", 100, "Foo", "Bar")` and it's working. I'm getting back a `null` result, but there's no exceptions. Same behaviour for those arguments from a .Net 4.0 desktop client and a WP7.1 client.

Comment: hmm, I am sending ("boudinitest", 1, "Standard", "User")
third argument must be "Standard"

Comment: Yeah - that's throwing in your server when called from a .Net 4.0 desktop application called with those exact same arguments; client.FetchStream("boudinitest", 1, "Standard", "User");

Comment: Do you know how I can debug this? I have administrator access on the server where the app is deployed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10739/discussion-between-mrmdavidson-and-user1027620)